# Angular 17 - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on getComputedStyle

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, popper.js, angular17

I am developing an Angular 17 app with @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 16.0.0.

After installing @ng-bootstrap and its dependencies (bootstrap 5.3.2, @popperjs/core 2.11.8) using ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, I started getting a [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEyt3.jpg) on all images in the page (inserted using the img tag).

The error comes from the popperjs' method [getComputedStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8lZp.jpg), that calls itself causing an infinite loop.

I encounter this error also when interacting with NgbDropdown elements, and only when compiling with ng build (with ng serve getComputedStyle gets called only once).

I use standalone components, so I imported from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap only specific components (like NgbDropdownModule).

*angular.json*

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "afi": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/afi",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
                "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
                "optimization": false,
                "budgets": [
                    {
                        "type": "initial",
                        "maximumWarning": "1200kb",
                        "maximumError": "3mb"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                        "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                        "maximumError": "4kb"
                    }
                ],
                "outputHashing": "none"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "afi:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "afi:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "afi:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
               "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "afi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any git repository so we can replicate and diagnose what is happening with your code?

Comment: @AbelChipepe yes, in this [repo](https://github.com/ele-rossi/angularEmpty/tree/main/afi) I tried to set up my environment in an empty angular app and, after adding a ngbDropdown in app.component.html and interacting with it, I get the same RangeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the `builder` property in the *angular.json* from `@angular-devkit/build-angular:application` to `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`.